# Why is req.route showing previous route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I have

```
const router = express.Router();

router
  .route('/:id') 
  .delete(
    validate(messageValidator.deleteById),
    MessageController.deleteById,
  )
  .get(
    validate(messageValidator.getById),
    MessageController.getById,
  );

router
  .route('/link-metadata')
  .get(
    validate(messageValidator.link),
    MessageController.getLinkMetadata,
  );
```

I don't know how but, when I make a request to /link-metadata, req.route is as below:
. [image]

This is giving me error, due to validation of first route requires Id to be Guid. It has been like this for over a year, now it is not working, if I put router
  .route('/link-metadata') ... above the /:id route, it works. Why is this happening?

Comment: My guess is that you should add some regex validation to your :id parameters (else it could be anything, include link-metadata for example). You can do it like this : `router.route('/:id([0-9]+)' etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the order.

`.route('/:id')` this means basically `/.*` so, any route will fall under this.

So, when you are hitting `/link-metada`, it is hitting the `/:id` route. Where `req.param.id` is `"link-metada"`.

Place your `/link-metadata` above the `/:id` route and it will work.